# ViewChildren for ng-template

Tags: angular

I have a angular2 component for which the template look like this:

```
<div>
    <div><ng-template #left></ng-template></div>
    <div><ng-template #right></ng-template></div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to retrieve a reference to all `ng-template` element using `ViewChildren` but I have no idea the type I need to pass between bracket.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.templates.toArray());
}
```

or

```
@ViewChild('left') left:TemplateRef;
@ViewChild('right') right:TemplateRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.left, this.right);
}
```

Comment: hey, I've just written [an article on DOM manipulation](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02#.lc9ev4gg0!) using `ViewContainerRef`, take a look if you have time.

Comment: visual studio code complaints about missing generics: `[ts] Generic type 'TemplateRef<C>' requires 1 type argument(s)` I don't know, shouldn't it be `ElementRef` ?

Comment: I'm not able to see what role the generic parameter would fulfill. `TemplateRef<Object>` should do IMHO.

Comment: The generic type is meant for the template context object. If you don't use a context object, just use `any`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is it possible to query the template when it's stamped out of ngTemplateOutlet?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess not. As far as I remember it only queries statically added content.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How to render that `@ViewChild` inside the `.html` template? I get a nice json-dump in `ngAfterViewInit(console.log(…))` but no luck in the html, i.e. `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="left">
        </ng-template>` :-(

Comment: @FrankNocke Sorry, it's too long ago that I look that I investigated such topics. You'll have to try somewhere else. I don't know.