# @ViewChildren(TemplateRef) is undefined for <template> elements

Tags: angular

How can I get a collection of all templates (TemplateRef) inside a component? It works fine with ViewChild but ViewChildren is undefined...

I use a solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567236/viewchildren-for-ng-template). [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lzofuya817LE4ZrPxNOG?p=preview) with the full example.

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div>
              <template #model>...</template>
              <template #color>...</template>
            </div>`
  })
  export class App {
  @ViewChild('model') model;
  @ViewChild('color') color;
  @ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.templates); // undefined
    console.log(this.model); // TemplateRef_ {...}
  }
}
```

I need `templates` for a grid component where it's possible to define templates for columns. Unfortunately ng-content [doesn't support](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563) dynamic projection, so I'm trying to achieve it with templates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you move `console.log('child', this.templates);` to `ngAfterViewInit()` then it works.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('child', this.templates);
}
```

I had expected it to work in `ngAfterContentInit()` as well. It seems in this Angular version `ngAfterContentInit()` runs before `ngAfterViewInit()`. I was sure this was the other way around earlier.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OIWOaRnJSCEHRIWuzvdx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need implements ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); in the end of function of any Children