# How to call ng-template by variable?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I checked:
[ViewChildren for ng-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567236/viewchildren-for-ng-template)
and 
[Access multiple viewchildren using @viewchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild/40165639#40165639)

But I am not able to call my template via the value of a variable...

So my template is like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let feature of Object.values(features)">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templates[feature]"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #myFeature>
  Nothing to see here
</ng-template>

<ng-template #myOtherFeature>
  Nothing to see here
</ng-template>
```

`features` is an enum with matching values to my templates names... then in my class, I tried to grab all the `ViewChildren` like this:

```
export class SomeClass {
   @ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
}
```

So the idea is that, i thought I should be able to reference the correct template by doing `templates[feature]` which should yield something like `templates['myFeature']` and give me the right template... but is not.

How do I archive this?

Comment: [ngTemplateOutlet]="templates['myFeature']" ?

Comment: If all you need is [ngTemplateOutlet]="templates['myFeature']" then can't you just have all the template names in a string[ ] i.e. 
```public templates : string[ ] = ['myFeature', 'myOtherFeature']```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid defining a the available templates manually?? That's what I tried to avoid with the `templates` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created different templates(different template variables), you need to create different view child for each of them. ViewChildren will work only if they are of same template reference variable. And the usage in your code it will fetch every template instance because you are passing `TemplateRef`, it will fetch every instance of this type.

I have created a stackblitz, which demonstrates [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7wsgb).

Also note, you template instance will be available only on `ngAfterViewInit()`, until then it would be undefined.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid defining a `ViewChild` for every template I got? I find this pretty stupid? I mean I may as well use a switch and call the template myself manually?

Comment: No I don't think so. Maybe someone else might have a different approach.

Comment: @codenamezero See my answer below to get what you are looking for with a single variable

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering inside the `ngAfterViewInit`, I got it working to the way I want it. Is a little bit ugly because I need to use a `setTimeout` and I need to play with the internal variables (not sure if this is a good idea)...

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrgban) the showcase dynamic template selection and rendering by variable value.

In a nutshell, here is how I did it, you need 3 things:

```
// to grab all the templates
@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
// to be use for template selection
templateMap: { [key: string]: TemplateRef<any> } = {};
// to avoid rendering during the first run when templateMap is not yet ready
templateMapReady = false;
```

Then in the `ngAfterViewInit` you do the following to build the `templateMap`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  // setTimeout to bypass the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  setTimeout(() => {
    // loop through the fetched template
    this.templates.toArray().forEach(t => {
      // for those ng-template that has a #name, they will have references
      const keys = Object.keys((t as any)._def.references);
      if (keys.length === 1) {
        // so we put these in the templateMap
        this.templateMap[keys[0]] = t;
      }
    });
    // now we change it to ready, so it would render it
    this.templateMapReady = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: Using a timeout to bypass change detection feels a bit wrong. Just use a different life cycle hook

Comment: Also, using private implementation details is bad.

Comment: I have since added a better workaround of using NgZone's onStable callback.

Comment: Hi, I can't see the new change neither in your post nor in your StackBlitz example. Nevertheless, check my edited answer above for a more concise and consistent solution

Answer (score 0):

### EXPLANATION

The **ViewChildren** directive will have its value stored right before **ngAfterViewInit()** ([see this](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#usage-notes)).

Angular checks your template at first and finds `templates` to be `undefined`.

It then starts to render the view. In the process, it resolves Template directives like `ViewChildren()` and calls `ngAfterViewInit()`.

In the process, `templates` gets set which means the view is now in an *inconsistent state*.

***The initial rendering of the page is causing a change to the page itself***.

That's when you get the infamous *"Expression has changed ..."* error.

### SOLUTION

You can't change when `templates` is set, as it's orchestrated by Angular.
What you **can** do though, is instead use *another variable* for the binding, and set it to `templates` once the initial view rendering is done.

Trying to set our new variable in `ngAfterViewInit()` will again trigger the "Expression has changed" error, since this life cycle hook itself is part of the initial rendering.

The solution is to defer the setting of the new variable in `ngAfterViewInit()` to the next VM turn.

To do this, we can simply use `setTimeout()` with no second argument:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates!: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
  features: TemplateRef<any>[] = [];
  name = "Angular";

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.features = this.templates.toArray());
  }
}
```

See this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ccjga)